# Missing "VCL Form" option in Delphi "File, New, Other Files" menu

Tags: forms, delphi

I was given a new laptop at work.  I had Delphi on my old laptop.  We only have 1 licence for Delphi.  It was removed from my old laptop and installed on my new laptop.

Normally I would go "File, New, VCL Forms Application" and start putting objects on the Main Form.  Then, I go to "File, New, Other Files" and I have only "Project Group" and "Text File" showing.  How do I get "VCL Form" to show?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v61hv.png)

[delphi](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v61hv.png)
[delphi other option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HnlZr.png)[delphi customise option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eeQGk.png)

Comment: Which Delphi version?

Comment: @jen Can you please [edit] your question to include screenshots of what you are actually seeing?

Comment: You have still not indicated which Delphi version. Anyway, you are entitled to free installation support from Embarcadero / Idera since you have a license. Please contact their support.

Comment: When you say that Delphi was removed from your old laptop do you mean it was Uninstalled or deactivated. Uninstalling Delphi does not deactivate licence for that specific computer. In fact licence files are kept on computer even after uninstallation. In order to deactivate your licence on specific computer you need to run Licence manager and deactivate the licence from there.

Comment: As for your new laptop I recommend you run licence manager on it and check the status of Delphi licence. It is possible that during installation process your license could not be activated. So by running licence manager you might fix that by trying to activate your Delphi again.

Answer (score 1):

That "Customize" option allows you to add items to the menu that you use most for your convenience.  If you select that, a dialog similar to this shows up:
[image]

Here, I've gone to the "Delphi Files" folder under Gallery Items and scrolled down until I found "Form".  Now I can just drag-and-drop it over to the right under Menu Items, click OK, and the next time I open the File > New menu, I'll see this:

[image]

Now this doesn't say "VCL Form" like you were expecting, but these screenshots were from Delphi XE and I think you're using a different version.  However, this does add a VCL Form to my project.

It should be noted that without customizing, you can always just go to File > New > Other and see all possibilities--including a Form.  Using Customize simply adds an often-used item for quicker access.

Answer (score 0):

In Embarcadero® RAD Studio 10.2 it looks like File->New and then you have options: VCL Forms Application-Delphi, VCL Form-Delphi and etc.

Comment: there are no VCL form options .  When I go file, new I have the options other or customise.   Other has project group and text file in it,    Customise  also has other files, project group and text files in it